# how to check if the user input an integer

Tags: c++, int

I need to check in my program if the user inputs an integer and not a character or string.
Character isn't that bad since it's pratically an integer, but if the user enters a sequence of characters then it just goes nuts.

I've made this function

```
int* ask_lung(int* lung)
{
int tmp; // length of a word

cout << "Inserisci la lunghezza della parola da indovinare: ";
cin >> tmp;

if(cin)
{
    // Se i è uguale a o minore di 0 allora ritorna all'inizio

    if(tmp <= 0)
    {
        cout << endl << "\tNon puoi inserire 0." << endl << endl;
        ask_lung(lung);
    }
    else
    {
                    // the error is about here, when it reaches this part of the code it keeps showing the first line "Inserisci la lunghezza della parola da indovinare: "
        *lung = tmp;
    }
}
else ask_lung(lung);

return lung;
}
```

Comment: What does this do/supposed to do ?

Comment: while( ! (cin >> myInt)){ std::cout << "Your input was not an int" << std::endl }

Or i understand something wrong?!

Comment: if tmp is <= 0 or a character or a character sequence it should print an error and ask again for the input

Comment: Why not do it in loop instead of doing it recursively? I.e. `while (!(cin >> tmp)) { /* Prompt user to enter a proper number */ }`. Also, if you don't want the number to be negative, declare `tmp` to be `unsigned`.

Comment: whith a while loop it just keeps showing the error i'm prompting like if the user was keeping typing wrong

Answer (score 2):

In case of  string of characters, your stream contains large number of invalid characters and you need to flush your stream of those characters to a new state. Instead of doing that recursively, it is better to do that in a loop. This would suffice for you reasonably.

```
while(true)
{
  cout << "Please Enter an Integer" << endl ;
  if (cin >> temp)  //true if a leading integer has entered the stream
    break ;
  else
  {
    cout << "Invalid Input" << endl ;
    cin.clear() ;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize> :: max(), '\n') ;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, just as i thought i had to clean the stream, now it works just fine.

Comment: can you explain me please cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize> :: max(), '\n'); ?

Comment: Do we need to handle the case of `12x<enter>` where the first part is an integer then there is some trash on the line?

Comment: @DomeWTF: If you enter an invalid character that is not an integer it sets the bad bad (this is why you need to call clear()). But it does not remove the bad character from the stream so if you loop it will repeatedly try and read the bad character. So the ignore() calls reads and drops all characters until the new line character ('\n').

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) along with [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) as:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

if ( std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isdigit) )
{
     //input is integer
}
```

Or, if you want to test and also want the integer, then it is better to use `input` as `int`, as suggested by other answer. You may consider using `std::stoi` if you have (read) the string already. Note that [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throws exception on error.

Comment: That has different semantics than` operator>> int`. Your version checks if all characters to the next space are digits. The problem here one input may be packed (ie age followed by name).

Comment: @LokiAstari:`1e3` is not an integer.

Answer (score -2):

The input is handled correctly, the problem is that you're returning a pointer to a local variable. That variable is on the stack, an it will be deallocated once the function returns. Instead you should just return the integer itself, not a pointer to it.

EDIT: I see that actually you're not returning a pointer to the integer, you're assigning to the integer that the pointer points to. Still, it's better to just return the integer itself.

Comment: `*lung = tmp` changes the value pointed to by `lung`, not its address. Input is not handled correctly either.